# Nvidia Shadowplay/Share last and next 5 minutes

Tags: recording, shadowplay

Is it possible to set Nvidia Shadowplay/Share to record the last X minutes and additionally the next X minutes?
I would love that features since I've recognized that I cut off a lot of commentary when creating clips.